# i want to use a button shortcut to open my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, button

Am making a Todo app in Flutter and i want to use a button shortcut  to open the app for example (double press the (volume up) button or press (volume down+ power button)).
so is there any package that can help me to achieve this ,or do i have to use some native code to do it??

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of such a feature. Have you seen it implemented somewhere?

Comment: no i just thought it would be cool to have quick access to the app to set reminders or tasks

Comment: Yeah sounds cool to me too but I'm not sure if it's possible. Since you're pretty much asking for the powers of the effect of key logging here.